# jQuery doesn't load in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, loaded

I've got a simple HTML file in which jQuery is included. In Safari it works but in Firefox it doesn't load. And when I use $ I get the following error message in firefox:

**ReferenceError: $ is not defined**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type='text/javascript' integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    if (window.jQuery) {
        alert("loaded");
    } else {
        alert("not loaded");
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when it tries to load the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the integrity attribute value is not matching with the hash value of the script.
Could you please check in console window if you are getting any error?

I have figured out the root cause. Based on caniuse site, safari does **NOT** implement this feature and hence you don't see the problem on safari. Same case for IE and Edge. Please see below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I Tried your code like this and it works

```
<!doctype html>

    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script>


        if (window.jQuery) {
            alert("loaded");
        } else {
            alert("not loaded");
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Usually I use the development version of firefox; for testing I downloaded Chrome and the the "normal" firefox and on both I get "not loaded" except Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, multiple function weren't working from Firefox and also Safari, I checked and noticed that one of them was outside the statement:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      //your code
    });
```

I got the function back inside it and everything was working fine. So try to include the (document).ready function in your script.
It seems that Chrome is the "smartest" in recognizing and executing jQuery.